# FreeSwitch invalid conference command

Tags: command, freeswitch

User dials  :   -- If the **Conference Num is invalid**, I want to be able to execute command from my python script.

```
Is there a command to send to freeswitch server to notify that the conference number
```

entered by user is invalid.

I can execute command to kick a user out of the conference. The command is "kick".

I do not want to kick a user out because than the audio played will be misleading to the user.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've not understood your scenario but you possibly could DEAF that user before KICK.
http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_conference